# Python3 time converter (invalid syntax)

Tags: python-3.x, math, syntax, converters, invalid-argument

```
print("Choose the unit to convert to")                                                                                  
print("Seconds = S")                                                                                                    
print("Minutes = M")                                                                                                    
print("Hours = H")                                                                                                      
choice = input("Enter (S/M/H): "                                                                                        
if choice == "S":                                                                                                               
    var5 = (var1 / var2)                                                                                                    
    print("Awnser:")
```

It says that the invalid syntax is the line with `if choice == "S":` 
and the invalid syntax is : behind "A"

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Choose the unit to convert to")
print("Seconds = S")
print("Minutes = M")
print("Hours = H")
var1 = 100
var2 = 10
var5 = 0 
choice = str(input("Enter (S/M/H):"))
print(type(choice))
if choice == "S":
    var5 = (var1 / var2)
print("Awnser: "+str(var5))
```

Hi it seems like your syntax was incorrect for the input function missing the closing bracket, I also added a string cast for your 'choice' variable

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your syntax:

The Error is in your this line:

```
choice = input("Enter (S/M/H): "
```

You Missed A `)` There

Try That I Simply Code For You:

```
print("Choose the unit to convert to")                                                                                  
print("Seconds = S")                                                                                                    
print("Minutes = M")                                                                                                    
print("Hours = H")                                                                                                      
choice = str(input("Enter (S/M/H): "))                                                                                        
if choice == "S":                                                                                                               
    var5 = (var1 / var2)                                                                                                    
    print("Awnser:")
```

And Also You Need To Add `Str` in choice variable